# Firefox incorrect file type in Save as type - Save as dialog

Tags: javascript, firefox, jpeg

I'm trying with FileSaver.js (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

When I save an image of type jpg, the save as dialog displaying in Firefox gives incorrect value at Save as type dropdown (It says "PNG Image (*.jpg), but what I expect is JPEG Image (*.jpg)).

Could anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out the reason for this issue.

I use canvas-toblob javascript library to convert a canvas to blob. But Firefox has internal implementation for toblob method, so the same method in canvas-toblob.js is never called.

I modify canvas-toblob.js so that Firefox will use the method in this library. This solved my issue

`if (HTMLCanvasElement) {
    canvas_proto.toBlob = function(callback, type /*, ...args*/) {
          if (!type) {
            type = "image/png";
        } if (this.msToBlob && /^\s*image\/png\s*(?:$|;)/i.test(type)) {
            callback(this.msToBlob());
            return;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify image/jpeg for the type parameter.

Comment: How can I do that? Please be specific

Comment: canvas.toBlob(function(blob){...},"image/jpeg")